# Set custom Source in NetSuite SalesOrder

Tags: mule, netsuite

Is there a way to set the Source field when creating a Sales Order using the web API?

I'm integrating a new web frontend for a client, and we are sending orders over the SuiteTalk SOAP API. Everything comes through okay, except the Source seems to be read only. It always says *Web Services* on the orders we create.

Previously, the client was using NetSuite's integrated/out-of-the-box store frontend. Orders created this way show up with a Source that includes the store name. The client uses the Source to help filter and create reports, and they have been relying on the fact that the Source includes the store name.

Is it possible to edit the Source?

We are using Mule ESB's NetSuite connector to handle communication with NetSuite. The connector exposes the Source field as a string, and I've tried putting in a text value of what I want to see.

The various record IDs are also strings, so maybe Source is really "source ID"? Not sure where I could find the Source's ID, though. The Source only shows up as text in both NetSuite's admin site and in the SalesOrder records (via the web service)

We are using API version 2013_1, but it *might* be possible to switch to a newer one of needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source field being read-only is by design. The value comes from the webstore. If a customer have multiple ecomm/webstore the source field will identify which store the sales order came from.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the 'source' field has always been readonly.  This field can only be set by NetSuite.  You cannot set this field using SuiteScript or SuiteTalk.

A possible workaround is to use a custom field and hide the default source field.  If you go this route, you will need to adjust any saved searches that uses the default source field.